# PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: relation "entries" does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku, activerecord

I'm trying to deploy a simple Rails app in heroku but I'm getting this message in the heroku logs: `PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "entries" does not exist`

My migration file is like this:

```
class CreateEntries < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :entries do |t|
      t.string :meal_type
      t.integer :calories
      t.integer :proteins
      t.integer :carbs
      t.integer :fats

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

I've tried a few thing(including changing the name of the migration file manuallly) but don't know what to do.

[terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0At5U.png)

Comment: migration should run in sequence, it is possible that some other migration is being run before `CreateEntries` & refers the `entries`. Check for the `t.references :entry` in your migrations.

Comment: Also you should not change the name of the migration file manuallly, rails adds the timestamps to filename to make sure migrations runs sequentially

Comment: What are your model relations? Is the error happening during the migration running?

Comment: There's only one model "Entry", the error shows when I run heroku logs on the  terminal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you run the migrations in heroku? if not then you can do it like this:
`heroku run rake db:migrate --app=your_app_name`

Answer (score 0):

Probably you don't have an 'entries' column on your DB